# Join 2 mysql queries, where the second query depends on the output of the first

Tags: php, mysql

I use my first query to get the id and name of the user like this:

```
select id,name from temp_card where sex='$sex' and city='$city' order by name ASC
```

Then I have a second query that uses the results from the first, and gets more data from another table:

```
select images from temp_card_images where temp_card_id=". $row['id'] ." order by id ASC limit 1
```

How can I combine these two queries so that I can print out the 3 fields (id, name and images) in a single while loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn about JOINs. This can be achieved like this

```
SELECT tc.id,tc.name,tci.images
FROM temp_card tc
    INNER JOIN temp_card_images tci ON tc.id=tci.temp_card_id
WHERE sex='$sex' 
  AND city='$city' 
GROUP BY tc.id
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: What if i want to select only one row from the temp_card_image table? For each result from the temp_card table, only one image?

Comment: @salmanhijazi If you only want one image then add a LIMIT. I have also added table aliases to the SELECT clause which should get round that error. If you want the temp_card_images id instead then you can just change tc.id to tci.id.

Comment: When I add limit one, it returns only one result. I want it to return 1 image for each temp_card row. The query works perfectly fine without the limit, but in that case it returns all the images for each temp_card row.

Comment: @salmanhijazi Ok I didn't quite understand. Do you mean you want the first entry (ORDERed BY name ASC) for each tc.id?

Comment: Suppose there are 10 rows in the temp_card table that meet my sex and city conditions. And for each row, there are 10 rows in the temp_card_images table. I want that the query returns all 10 rows from the temp_card table, but only 1 row for each from the temp_card_images table. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

You needs to perform a JOIN query

```
select tc.id, tc.name, tci.images from temp_card tc
left join temp_card_images  tci
on tc.id = tci.temp_card_id
where tc.sex='$sex' and tc.city='$city' order by tc.name ASC
```

Comment: What if both the tables have a column by the name id. How do we specify which to use?

Comment: using the table name with the column name like `temp_card.id`

Comment: I got this error: Notice: Uncovered an error in your SQL query script: "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous". It points to my database class file. and the line that it points to is: trigger_error('Uncovered an error in your SQL query script: "' . $this->error() . '"');

Comment: Surely it's better to use an INNER JOIN here? What if tc.id doesn't exist in tci.temp_card_id?

Comment: liquorcivar, i used your query too, but encountered the same error. I'm not sure where the fault is.

Comment: What if i want to select only one row from the temp_card_image table? For each result from the temp_card table, only one image

Answer (score 0):

Although unrelated, I would highly recommend looking into using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) as your database access layer. It works with most database types like MySQL, SQLite, etc.. and it will help against SQL injection to your database.